# Question regarding checking points in upvoting for an answer.

Tags: support, reputation

For an answer to a question, I am receiving 18 points. But I could see in the post only one upvote has taken place. For what I am having extra 8 points. How to check when we are receiving extra points?

For example, See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1059435/a-question-about-surjective-functions/1059496#1059496)

I got only one upvote but I receive 18 points for this. Why this is so?

Comment: You got 2 upvotes and 1 downvote for 2 x 10 + 1(-2)=18 points and a total score of 2-1 = 1.

Answer (score 4):

You got 2 upvotes and 1 downvote. The net effect is:

- score $2-1 = 1$
- reputation gain $2\cdot10-1\cdot2 = 18$

Since you don't have 1000 reputation points yet, you could not see the vote split yourself. Users with 1000 reputation can see them by clicking the score.

However, I made a [bookmarklet](http://dropproxy.com/f/7FC#split)  that shows vote split, regardless of your reputation. To use it:

1. drap the bookmarklet to the bookmark bar
2. jump to the answer by following the link in your question
3. click the bookmarklet.

(The bookmarklet works on both questions and answers, depending on the URL present in the URL field of your browser.)